# Fast / built-in bit-manipulation in Python/numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, bit-manipulation

I'm using an external library that outputs a numpy array w/ data type ">u2" (big-endian, unsigned, 2-byte / 16-bit). In my case, only 10-bits are effective (the output is from a hardware device that actually outputs **little-endian**). For example:

`65283` is the max value, corresponding to `bin(65283)=0b1111111100000011` as the direct python output, or `00001111111111` if it were little-endian.

I would like to map the range `0-65283` output from the library to the range `0-1023` that makes sense from the 10-bit hardware capability. How do I do this?

I've tried the following:

```
>>>import numpy as np

>>>arr=np.array([65283, 6528, 652, 65, 6], dtype=">u2")
>>>print arr/64  # same as arr/2**6 and arr >> 6
[1020  102   10    1    0]
>>>print arr.byteswap()
[ 1023 32793 35842 16640  1536]
```

But this does not give the desired result. What I've found is that the `bin()` function outputs in big-endian format (in the case of this numpy array), but with padded zeros omitted. For example, 65283 has all 16-bits represented, but `bin(6528)=0b1100110000000` (missing 3 zeros in the middle).

To fix this (and return a 10-bit little-endian number), I can get the binary form of 6528, add 3 zeros in the middle, and do a byte-swap. But 1) this is super tedious (done per element) and 2) the zero-padding is inconsistent (e.g. 652 requires 6 more zeros).

Is there a built-in way to do this? It looks like the `struct` module (w/ `pack` and or `unpack`) might help, but it's Greek to me right now. Any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT**:

Believe I've found the culprit. My example above (taking an actual value from the camera/library of 65238 and assuming semi-arbitrary additional values, which just have the right-most digit removed, obviously) wouldn't happen! e.g. 6528 requires a 1 in the least-significant byte (`00011001**1**0000000`) and that would never happen (only 10-bits are effective).

Upon further inspection, a simple `arr.byteswap()` in my code (where `arr` has legitimate values) works. e.g.:

```
>>>arr=np.array([12288, 13312, 12800, 12032, 13312, 13824, 65283, 0, 7936], dtype=">u2")
>>>arr.byteswap()
array([  48,   52,   50,   47,   52,   54, 1023,    0,   31], dtype=uint16)
```

I had never actually tried that in my code, only in this made-up example. Sorry for the confusion. But hopefully it may help someone else stumbling around this problem (especially if you use Basler cameras!), which turned out to be trivial I guess...

Answer (score 0):

```
import struct
struct.pack('<H',val)
```

or, better yet:

```
>>> arr.byteswap().newbyteorder()
array([65283,  6528,   652,    65,     6], dtype=uint16)
>>> arr.byteswap().newbyteorder().tostring()
'\x03\xff\x80\x19\x8c\x02A\x00\x06\x00'
```

[docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.byteswapping.html)

Comment: Hmm. What do I do w/ the return from `arr.byteswap().newbyteorder().tostring()` to get it into a 10-bit uint16 (or int16)? (Could be a dumb question; trying to figure that out now; will reply if I do) :)  Thanks...

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I need to map this array of `>u2` values (0-65283) to the range (0-1023). `>u2` has 16-bits, but in this particular array only 10-bits are effective (which is why it maxes out at 65283, or, `00001111111111` in little-endian, `1111111100000011` in big-endian. So, 65283 would be 1023. 0 would be 0. Something in the middle, like 6528 (in `>u2`) would be `1100110000000000` in big-endian, and so, `0000000011001100` (=204) in little-endian. Of course I'd rather not convert 6528 (e.g.) into a string representation of its binary form, pad it w/ however many 0s are required, and then convert to an int.

Comment: What do you mean map? There is no one to one map from a set with 65284 elements to a set with only 1024 elements.

Comment: It wouldn't be one-to-one of course. There's a dynamic range problem. 6528 would map to 204. But so would (maybe) 6529, 6527, 6526, etc. You lose resolution, but such resolution never existed in my data in the first place. Does that make sense?

Comment: I think I sort of understand what you're saying, but there is no way anyone can guess which are the "effective" bits you are talking about unless you very clearly state that in the question. I think also giving a table of input values -> output you want would help.

Comment: You're right. Let me think about how to edit the question for a second, and I'll do that.